# Will police help me if I my motorcycle is stolen but has an active tracker that is transmitting information in Canada?

Tags: police, vehicle, theft, crime

So, I got a new motorcycle, and it is natural for me to wonder about its security. Since I would be moving back to US in about 1 year, I am planning on not getting insurance.

That being said, I am thinking to install an anti theft GPS device which has a battery that lasts about two days.

God forbid but lets assume that someone takes my motorcycle, and I find it out within a few hours that it is missing.

If the tracker is working, would police be so helpful generally as to dispatch a team to recover the motorcycle if I inform them?

Comment: You are legally required to have insurance on a motorcycle in almost every U.S. state.

Answer (score 4):

### Probably

Police like to solve crimes and going straight to a location where they know a stolen vehicle is seems like an easy win.

However, there is no *legal* obligation for them to do so.